# how to make a sliding window float above the main activity using jfeinstein10 sliding menu

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

I am using jfeinstein10 sliding menu.
I would like to make the sliding window transparent and float above the main window so that the main window will be visible while the user open the sliding window.

at the moment the sliding menu is open from left to right so that the main window is shrinks to the right.
please help :)